# MBProgressHUD UIWebView

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, mbprogresshud

got a little problem with MBProgressHUD. I have a webview and want to display the HUD while the data is loading.
The HUD appears but stays only for a few seconds and disappears already but the webview didn't finish with loading.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

// Should be initialized with the windows frame so the HUD disables all user input by covering the entire screen
HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithWindow:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];

// Add HUD to screen
[self.view.window addSubview:HUD];

// Regisete for HUD callbacks so we can remove it from the window at the right time
HUD.delegate = self;

HUD.labelText = @"Loading";
HUD.detailsLabelText = @"updating data";

// Show the HUD while the provided method executes in a new thread
[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadingWebView) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];}

- (void) loadingWebView {

NSString *fullURL = beverageViewString; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL]; 
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]; 
[beverageView loadRequest:requestObj];
NSLog(@"%@",beverageViewString);}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove the showWhileExecuting method and hide hud in the below delegate method of UIWebView then it will work fine

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [HUD hide:YES];
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Didn't get it. If I remove showWhileExecuting it doesn't appear at all. Could you please explain in detail.

Comment: this line no need [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(loadingWebView) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];

Comment: If I delete this line the HUD doesn't appear at all.

Comment: hud init like HUD = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];

Answer (score 1):

We never integrated web view with MBProgressView HUD , instead of using this you should to use UIActivityIndicator over here and stop & resignFromSuperView at this delegate of webView:

> - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView

u can manually hide HUD at this delegate :

```
 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
   [HUD hide:YES];
   if(HUD!=nil)
   { 
       [HUD removeFromSuperview];
       [HUD release];
       HUD=nil;
   }
}
```

Comment: '[HUD retainCount]>0' is complete nonsense.

Comment: @bbum : so it is . i admit the thing , it was by mistake , but now i update this.,